# Is there a way using JS to check if IE SmartScreen is on?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dhtml

Is there a way using JS to check if IE SmartScreen is on?
I want my site to check if SmartScreen is enabled for user browser.
If not using JS then how?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no API for SmartScreen that is available from within the browser. This would defeat the purpose since malicious sites would be able to use this information to try and get around the filter.

Comment: If adding IsSmartScreenOn API can help to get around the filter then how goo it is :)?  are you 100 sure that there is no way?

Comment: If there was a SmartScreenOn API available in the browser than malicious sites that have not yet been flagged could determine whether or not it is safe to redirect to a malicious site that has been flagged. If SmartScreen is off, the redirect happens. If it's on, it redirects to a safe site since it knows the flagged site would be blocked.  I'm 99.9% sure there is no way to get this information from within the browser without using an exploit of some kind to get access to the host.